# Does Read Uncommitted violates Atomcity?

Tags: sql, acid

We know database transaction guarantees ACID(Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability). SQL provides Read Uncommitted Isolation Level, with this level set, reader may read out dirty data during a transaction, and the dirty data may be discarded if the transaction is rolled back.

But I think, this behavior also violates Atomicity.

Say, we have

```
a = 0
b = 0
```

session A executes transaction:

```
begin
set a = 1
// continues...
```

another session B read from database:

```
get a, b => a=1, b=0
```

session A continues

```
set b = 2
commit
```

The read process reads out(a=1, b=0), isn't this a violations of Atomicity? I only expect either (a=0, b=0) or (a=1, b=2) will meets Atomicity, never (a=0, b=2) or (a=1, b=0).

Comment: It also violates Isolation in my opinion (because one transaction can see uncommitted changes done by another transaction). Note that not every DBMS actually supports read uncommitted

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_uncommitted